# UIImageView shifted when I click my back button

Tags: xcode, uiimageview

I've got a small project with two `UIImageView`-based nib files.

When the main view loads, it looks correct.

To switch between views, I'm using code like this (for example, this is to go to second view)

```
-(IBAction) secondClicked:(id)sender {
    SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:main animated:NO];
    [second release];
}
```

When the new view is shown, it's shifted sideways about 10% of screen.   Using similar code to go back to main results in the main view being shown similarly offset.

I'm in landscape mode, if that makes a difference.

How can I display the views so they're correctly aligned?

Comment: Is the size of the new view you are loading not a full window size?

Comment: all the views are full window size; they show up the correct *size* but just shifted to the left or right.

Comment: That makes no sense to me. Double check your nib files uiview sizes, or if you are shifting in code the uiview frame

Comment: what keywords would I look for in code?  the nib files are all correct.  (the main menu shows up correctly aligned when the app opens)

Answer (score 0):

Ok it makes sense now that I looked more carefully. Why are you presening a view controller modally when you wish to go back? How did you showed this viewController initially? If it was through a navigation controller you should pop the view

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If it was presented modally you should just dismiss it!

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: sweet; this looks like it will do it to go *back*, but going from the main to the subview this won't work.

Comment: But this code is only for going back. Not forward (presenting a view)

Comment: I agree.  But I'm having the problem also when I go forward so this doesn't fully solve it for me.  I can see how my question can be confusing, so I'll fix it now.